# Definitions of cluster and condensation points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Pugh in Real Mathematical Analysis defines $p$ as a **cluster** point of $S$ if each $M_rp$ (r-neighborhood of $p$) contains *infinitely* many points of $S$. He defines $p$ as a  **condensation** point if each $M_rp$ contains *uncountably* many points of $S$.

I have a few questions because this doesn't make sense yet.

Is it true that all condensation points of $S$ are also cluster points? Because uncountably many implies infinitely many but not vice versa.

Is the following true? If we take any point in $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, it is a condensation point. If we take any point in $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ it's a cluster point because the rationals are denumerable.

Is there any set in $\mathbb{R}$ that has cluster points that aren't condensation points? I don't get how a point in a subset $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (or most metric spaces, in fact) can have each r-neighborhood contain *infinitely* many points of $S$ but not *uncountably* many.

Perhaps Pugh just didn't motivate these definitions enough and I'll see their uses later....

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to :

$$X:=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n},n\geq 1\} $$

You see that a $0$ is  a cluster of $X$ but not condensation point.

However your affirmation condensation $\Rightarrow$ cluster is true (at least if you admit the countable axiom of choice).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first three questions is yes. As for your last question,$\Bbb Q$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$ which has cluster points which aren't condensation points. Another example, take any convergent sequence of distinct points in $\Bbb R$.